# why does internationalization menu i18n_menu translate but never localizes?

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

I have a menu set to :

Translate and Localize. Menu items with language will allow translations. Menu items without language will be localized.

And I have include menu items that are "language neutral" and provided translations for said items.

Nothing but the original 'language neutral' language ever shows regardless of what the users profile language is set to (user's profile language is the primary way I have translation determining what language to use)

What do I have to do to get the Menu items to localize to the current users current profile language ?

Answer (score 1):

As said in the 2nd choice Translate and Localize, there are two different ways for translating menus.

If you want to use the **Menu items with language will allow translations** option, set a link in each of your defined languages, but none in language neutral, and check in *admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu* then in *admin/structure/menu/item/[ITEM_ID]/edit* for each set of translation, that it is correctly translated.

Now if you wish to work with the **Menu items without language will be localized** option,  make sure you create the menu item in the site default language (because localization always happens from the site's default language to other languages). And choose *language neutral* for the menu item when created.

Now in the opened up Translate tab, you'll translate the menu item title and description instead of creating another menu item. And you're done !

For a complete explanation read this nice tutorial about [Drupal multilingual navigation](http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2011-nov-19/drupal-7s-new-multilingual-systems-part-8-menu-languages-and-translation).

Comment: Thanks Kojo. I've actually been through that link. The issue I have is that only the original (lang neutral) entry for the link title ever displays regardless of the fact that the localized titles have been provided.

Comment: I see. did you try to set path prefix as primary choice and see if works then ?

Comment: I did not. The project requires that the user's profile language needs to be primary choice. Any particular reason you think that will help?

Comment: Not really, but if you already checked all basic settings and think they are correct, my idea was you might play around with other settings like language primary choice in order to make sure localized menu translations "never" display, before searching elsewhere, like conflicts btw modules version, patches needed or whatever ...