# Menu links duplicated on node/%node/edit pages

Tags: 7, routes, i18n-l10n

I've a strange problem.
I've a multilingual site with many menus configures as "Translate and localize".

Everything works, every menu link has his language, but ONLY when I go to a node/%nid/edit page the system prints all links, on both language (on every language)

This behaviour there is on every theme. I've i18n modules enabled.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the function _i18n_menu_link_process of i18n_module.

```
<?php    
    /**
     * Check whether this link is to be processed by i18n_menu and start processing.
     */
    function _i18n_menu_link_process(&$link) {
      // Only visible links that have a language property and haven't been processed
      // before. We also check that they belong to a menu with language options.
      if (empty($link['i18n_menu']) && !empty($link['language']) && !empty($link['access']) && empty($link['hidden']) && i18n_menu_mode($link['menu_name'])) {
        // Mark so it won't be processed twice.
        $link['i18n_menu'] = TRUE;
        // Skip if administering this menu or this menu item.
        if (arg(0) == 'admin' && arg(1) == 'structure' && arg(2) == 'menu') {
          if (arg(3) == 'manage' && $link['menu_name'] == arg(4)) {
            return FALSE;
          }
          elseif (arg(3) == 'item' && arg(4) == $link['mlid']) {
            return FALSE;
          }
        }
        // Skip if administering this menu item through the node edit form.
        elseif (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(2) == 'edit') {
          return FALSE;
        }
        return TRUE;
      }
      else {
        return FALSE;
      }
    }
?>
```

This function returns TRUE or FALSE when checking if a menu link should be "hidden" (and so not displayed). At the end this value "hidden" is TRUE for link of a language different from current user language.

This function EXCLUDES this "hidden => TRUE" value when the request page is node/%nid/edit, and I don't understand way.

So there are two solutions:

- apply a patch to this function
- declare in a custom module the hook_translated_menu_link_alter, force this hook to run AFTER i18n_menu and apply my "logic"

And, obviously, ask on drupal.org the reason of this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i fully understand the question, but please take a look to this post:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/96963/30465

It seems related to your question.

I this it will be related to the language configuration fallback (since there is no language suffix inlcuded)

You could for example try

http://www.example.com/en/node/%nid/edit

if that works correctly (and only shows the engish menu links), you know that it will be a problem with language fallback.

Hope this helps, feel free to let me now if you need more!! :)

Comment: My links are not "language neutral", the problem is this. And that this bug appears only on one page..

Comment: Dear arribu, i have a multilingual setup on my sandbox at home, will take a look there and report back in a couple hours

Comment: Guardian, I've posted the solution.. I think it's absurd -.-

Comment: Arrubio, thanks for posting and getting back to me on this as well. It is very weird indeed...This needs some looking into imho